# how to get output as text while input is in the numeric form

Tags: oracle, plsql

how to get output of numeric/numbers in character/alphabet form?
like i give input:- 1234
then output should be like:- one two three four AND (in other condition) one 
                             thousand two hundred thirty four.

Comment: have a look at [this](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1407603857650)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
select to_char(to_date(1234, 'j'), 'jsp') from dual
```

Output will be
one thousand two hundred thirty-four

Comment: Note that this only works with values up to 5373484. That may be all the OP needs though.

Comment: you can use directly without select in SP
eg., to_char(to_date(1234, 'j'), 'jsp')

Comment: please explain with the procedure program.. thank you

Comment: you post the sample SP in which you want to use this. After that I will add and explain you

Comment: @D'Mayal See the Gaj's previous comment (at 10:21Z) - you can assign `to_char(to_date(1234, 'j'), 'jsp')` to a variable in the procedure.

Comment: i don't know how to make procedure with it.. i just want to input digits and get a output.. so please make a procedure for it and post it.. thank you

Comment: In this case you have to write function

create or replace function num_to_txt(p_num number) return varchar2(500)
as 
begin
    return to_char(to_date(p_num, 'j'), 'jsp');
end;

Comment: yeah.. its working.. thank you.. but if i want output of 1234 as one two three four then?

Comment: Can you try this

create or replace function num_to_txt (p_num number)
return varchar2(500)
    v_str varchar2(500);
Begin
    For i in 1..length(v_num) Loop
        v_str := v_str || to_char(to_date(substr(v_num, i, 1), 'j'), 'jsp');
    End Loop;
    return v_str;
End;

I don't have oracle here

Comment: yeah its working.. but output comes without space like:- onetwothreefour

Comment: Change v_str := v_str||’ ‘||to_char(to_date(substr(v_num,i, 1),’j’),’jsp’); and change return statement to return ltrim(v_str);

Answer (score 0):

Execute below function.

```
            CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION NUMTOWORDS (P_IN IN NUMBER)
               RETURN VARCHAR2
            IS
               V_WORDS    VARCHAR2 (20) := '';
               V_CHAR     VARCHAR2 (20) := '';
               V_LENGTH   NUMBER;

               TYPE ARRAY_TYPE IS VARRAY (10) OF VARCHAR2 (10);
               V_ARRAY    ARRAY_TYPE := ARRAY_TYPE ('ZERO', 'ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE', 'FOUR', 'FIVE', 'SIX', 'SEVEN', 'EIGHT', 'NINE');
            BEGIN
               SELECT   LENGTH (TO_CHAR (P_IN)) INTO V_LENGTH FROM DUAL;

               FOR I IN 1 .. V_LENGTH
               LOOP
                  V_CHAR := V_ARRAY ( (TO_NUMBER (SUBSTR (TO_CHAR (P_IN), I, 1)) + 1));
                  V_WORDS := CONCAT (V_WORDS, CONCAT (V_CHAR, ' '));
               END LOOP;

               RETURN TRIM (V_WORDS);
            END;
```

"" SELECT NUMTOWORDS(674) FROM DUAL;